# Detect a specific line from a image using R

Tags: r, image-processing

[image]

I am new to image processing. I want to detect a specific line in this image, which is the horizontal line in the middle of it. I am wondering how to approach it. This is the map, and it has already been simplified to the edge map.

Comment: the source of that picture is vector data (map data), right?

Comment: the source of the pic is raster data

Comment: Don't vandalize your own posts please.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one method.

Let's start by reading in your image. We'll use the `png` library for this, so if you don't have it installed, you'll want to `install.packages("png")` first.

```r
library(png)

img_link <- "https://i.stack.imgur.com/PygvJ.png"

img <- readPNG(readBin(img_link, "raw", 1e6))
```

The `readPNG` function extracts the image as an array. In this case, the array is 360 by 371 by 4:

```r
dim(img)
#> [1] 360 371   4
```

This means the image is 360 by 371 pixels and contains four channels: red, blue, green and alpha (transparency).

We can plot this array at any time by calling:

```r
plot(as.raster(img))
```

[image]

To find a horizontal red line, all we need to do is look at the row sums of the pixel values in the green channel, which will drop sharply at the target row.

```r
sum_green <- apply(img[,,2], 1, sum)
```

We can plot this vector to ensure there is a row with a large drop-off in one of the rows, as we would expect.

```r
plot(sum_green, type = "l")
```

[image]

To get this row, we just find the minimum row sum:

```r
target_row <- which.min(sum_green)

target_row
#> [1] 183
```

So our red line is on the 183rd row. To prove this, let's make the 183rd row of our image black and draw it again:

```
img[target_row, , 1:3] <- 0

plot(as.raster(img))
```

[image]

This looks correct.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful. Just wondering, if, I need to detect the vertical line, is it gonna be the same way to approach it?

Comment: Yes, except do `apply(img[,,2], 2, sum)` (note the 2 instead of 1 in the second argument to `apply`